# vue3 with vite can't import CommonJS module

Tags: javascript, import, vuejs3, es6-modules, vite

## What is happning

On **vue2.6** + **webpack**, an application as follow is working well.

```
<template>
<v-app>
  <QR/>
  <v-main>
  </v-main>
</v-app>
</template>

<script>
import QR from 'qrcode-of-this-site'
export default {
  components: {QR},
}
</script>
```

Where [qrcode-of-this-site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode-of-this-site) imported at line#10 is my **ES6** module and using another external **CommonJS** module [qrcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode).

However, on **vue3.2** + **vite**, this application reports an error as follows:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/qrcode/lib/browser.js?v=0df8a00b' does not provide an export named 'default' (at QRcode.vue:11:8)
```

### watching files

The file **/node_modules/qrcode/lib/browser.js** is as follows:

```
...

exports.create = QRCode.create
exports.toCanvas = renderCanvas.bind(null, CanvasRenderer.render)
exports.toDataURL = renderCanvas.bind(null, CanvasRenderer.renderToDataURL)

// only svg for now.
exports.toString = renderCanvas.bind(null, function (data, _, opts) {
  return SvgRenderer.render(data, opts)
})
```

**QRcode.vue** is as follows:

```
<template>
  <v-layout column align-center class="white--text">
    <v-flex>
      <canvas id="qr"></canvas>
    </v-flex>
    QR code for this App
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
import QRCode from 'qrcode';
export default {
  mounted: function(){
    var currentUrl = window.location.origin;
    console.log(currentUrl);
    QRCode.toCanvas(document.getElementById('qr'),
      currentUrl, { toSJISFunc: QRCode.toSJIS }, function (error) {
      if (error) console.error(error)
      console.log('success!')
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Also, I've tried `import {toCanvas} from 'qrcode';` at line #11 of QRcode.vue, and the error is reported as follows:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/qrcode/lib/browser.js?v=0df8a00b' does not provide an export named 'toCanvas' (at QRcode.vue:11:9)
```

even **toCanvas** is certainly exported by **/node_modules/qrcode/lib/browser.js**

### My question

Can't the pair of **vue3** and **vite** import the **CommonJS** module as a default?
Are there any necessary settings to run this app?

### Reproducing environment

The full environment for reproducing is available as follows:

- Vue2 env (working well) https://github.com/UedaTakeyuki/QRcodeVue2
- Vue3 env (import error) https://github.com/UedaTakeyuki/QRcodeVue3

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that the `qrcode-of-this-site` package you created uses an CommonJS module which Vite can't work with and will not transpile at default or [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-commonjs) would do either. There are two ways to fix this:

- Build `qrcode-of-this-site` differently so it will transpile the CommonJS module to an ESM one so it would work for Vite (or build it accordingly for all module conventions).
- Use dependency pre-bundling. Like below:

```
// vite.config.js

export default defineConfig({
  ...
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ["qrcode"],
  },
});
```

I made a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-u8d78u?file=vite.config.js) with the last option as working example. Read more about this solution [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html#the-why).

Comment: You second point here is gold, I could have saved myself hours if I found it sooner.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i was able to fix the error on local dev server but on build it shows RollupError: module is not exported by package/dist/index.js, any idea on this issue?

Comment: If you navigate to the link in my post you'll see how to make it work for the production build. Here is it too: https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html#monorepos-and-linked-dependencies

Comment: do you know the difference between optimizedep transpiling VS using commonjsOptions config?