# Vue.js app on Vite cannot import a local module. "Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module does not provide an export named 'Plugin' (at main.js)"

Tags: vue.js, vite, rollupjs

I'm building a local Vue.js component library module, as well as a separate Vite + Vue.js app which consumes this library.

As info, the library plugins are produced with Rollup.js and the app is running on Vite `v4.4.11`.

**Note:** This issue has only occurred since I converted the consuming application from Webpack 4 to Vite.

## The Problem

I receive this error in the browser console of the app that imports the library:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/dist/library.js?t=1701123362821' does not provide an export named 'Plugin' (at main.js?t=1701123362821:3:10)

The `main.js` file imports the library plugin:

```js
import { Plugin as AtxVue3Plugin } from '../dist/library.js';
/*...*/
demoApp.use(AtxVue3Plugin);
```

The compiled CommonJS `library.js` file includes this:

```js
/*...*/
exports.Plugin = Plugin;
/*...*/
exports.default = Plugin;
```

I also have an ESM version: `library.mjs`:

```js
export {/*...*/ Plugin, /*...,*/ Plugin as default };
```

### Trying with a default export

I also tried making the plugin utilze a default export — it was actually my original strategy — but I received the same error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/dist/library.js?t=1701123362821' does not provide an export named 'default' (at main.js?t=1701123362821:3:10)

The library source `index.js` exports the module like this:

```js
const Plugin = { /*...*/ };

export default Plugin;
```

And the `import` statement in `main.js` looks like this:

```js
import AtxVue3 from '../dist/library.js';
```

Comment: The syntax error you have pasted has 'default' spelled incorrectly: `...does not provide an export named 'deafult'`. Presumably you've mispelled 'default' in your actual code

Comment: No, that's just a typo in the comment.

Comment: Fixed the typo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74845363/vue3-with-vite-cant-import-commonjs-module

Comment: Vite should be configured to work with CJS, it's unknown how it's done on your side. The question doesn't show if you tried to use library.mjs, which would be a reasonable move with Vite